# Links are unclickable

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi,

I have managed a blog(wordpress) for a company and pasted their header footer code to make the site look uniform. But the social icons in header are not clickable whereas they are clickable in rest of the website. Link to the blog is: [Blog](https://www.dwtltd.com/blog)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
.social > li > a
    {
    padding:5px 3px;
    }

.top-bar a
    {
    background:#0091EA none repeat scroll 0 0;
    z-index:9999;
    position:relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
.top-bar {
    background: #0091ea none repeat scroll 0 0;
    clear: both;
    color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    position: relative;
}
```